# can we apply django ordering on a field of SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a created a method field like

```
matchCount= serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_match')

def get_match(self, obj):
    likes = obj.post.count
    #here will be logic of almost 120 lines so cant use annotate*  
    return likes / time if time > 0 else likes
```

Now I want to  order on basis of this filed  **matchCount**. what can be best solution in this case ?  until now I found other developers are using annotate etc but as this logic is dynamic and will count match on run time , what can I do to sort on basis of this field ?

**Note :**  if you guys have a better solution for this kindly suggest , any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In standard DRF I couldn't find it anywhere in the serializer documentation.

However if you use [this library](https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest) you can specify the field to sort by in the query string.

EDIT:

If you use the above library you'll have to change your ModelSerializer into DynamicModelSerializer, ModelViewSet to DynamicModelViewSet, Router to DynamicRouter, etc as they say in the readme.

Then you shoulde able to use a url like `GET /yourendpoint/?sort[]=matchCount`

Comment: can you please give small example ?